# Network drive: move generates an error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, scripting

I'm trying to create a script in an application. The application should call `cmd.exe` and `cmd.exe` should run a statement

```
pushd \\file\share && move filename.txt \\file\share\newfilename.txt && popd
```

But this generates an error in an application

```
Program terminated with exit code <1>
```

When I run the same statement just replace move with copy, everything works fine

```
pushd \\file\share && copy filename.txt \\file\share\newfilename.txt && popd
```

Also `ren` and `del` are producing the same result as move. Any ideas why this is happening? All these works from the command prompt just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will most likely be a permissions issue. To `move` the file you need to have permission to delete (modify) both the source and the destination. This also explains why `del` and `ren` fail while copy works (only write permission required).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it is a permission problem, but I cannot understand why move command works from the command line using the same crendentials...

Comment: @jrara: You should add that information to your question.